# ASP.net Web API: change class name when serializing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a Data Transfer Object class for a product

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

When the Asp.net serializes the object in JSON (using `JSON.NET`) or in `XML`, it generates `ProductDTO` objects.

However, i want to change the name during serialization, from `ProductDTO` to `Product`, using some kind of attributes:

```
[Name("Product")]
public class ProductDTO
{
    [Name("ProductId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: How is the name ProductDTO present when an instance is serialized to JSON? JSON is untyped after all, and when I try to serialize an instance with JSON.NET, the class name isn't present.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't see why the class name should make it into the JSON-serialized data, but as regards XML you should be able to control the type name via [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585243.aspx), specifically via the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.name.aspx) property:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract(Name = "Product")]
public class ProductDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name="ProductId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

DataContractAttribute is relevant because the default XML serializer with ASP.NET Web API is [DataContractSerializer](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter). DataContractSerializer is configured through DataContractAttribute applied to serialized classes and [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) applied to serialized class members.

Comment: About "class name into JSON-serialized data": you are right, JSON doesn't outputs the class name, this is just for XML.

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use the default [.Net Serialization attributes](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) for this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Product")]
public class ProductDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProductId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```